# PHP seamless application

Tags: php, ajax

Hello all and thanks for taking the time to view this.

I want to make a PHP application and I am about to start, but I want the front/backend to have as little page loads as possible, but I just don't know what to learn per se. I am torn as to whether I should learn Ajax, AngularJS, EmberJS, NodeJS, BackboneJS, etc?

I really want to know if AJAX is the same as the others I listed or not. I just want to use PHP as the engine to fetch data from an SQL DB and make the application's front/backend seamlessly.

I would like to be pointed in the "right" direction as to which technology to take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use angularJS for faster loading of pages, learning path is first you have knowledge of ajax, then you can learn AngularJs.

here is a reason why you can use angularJs

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/3-reasons-to-choose-angularjs-for-your-next-project--net-28457

and you are going to use PHP as Backend so it eliminate node.js from this list, AngularJs is best as you have describe your requirement, if you know bit of javascript learning cure for angularJs is easy.

Comment: I do have some knowledge of Ajax but from what I learned I thought it was a tedious to write so many settings on the JS file that does the heavy lifting for every PHP script I am going to write, am I correct? 

And I do know JS (a bit). So you can work with PHP doing the backend stuff and Angular doing the requests asynchronously?

Comment: ok ajax is for knowledge only, otherwise angular manages all the things for you, you just have to learn syntax, and how can you integrate it with your needs, it is better if you use any php framework(i prefer laravel) with angular, so it become more easier to work with it., and yes angular doing request asynchronously.  

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Y6LM4Y_K6c   (for learning)